# How come my JSON returns NULL rows after each result?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data off a company register, So far it works to scrape each search result, however when i try exporting it. it show a null objects after each search result, as though it scrapes the same page twice?

[image]

THis is a snippet of the log.

```
2019-05-14 08:19:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/ltd/a-c-1> (referer: https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/Company/Find?q=a)
2019-05-14 08:19:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/ltd/a-c-1>
{'location': u'BEANCROFT ROAD', 'postal_code': None, 'company_name': u'A C PLC', 'address': u'BEANCROFT FARM'}
2019-05-14 08:19:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/ltd/a-c-1>
{'location': None, 'postal_code': None, 'company_name': None, 'address': None}
```

And finally my code

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

  name = 'CYRecursive'
  start_urls = [
      'https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/Company/Find?q=a']

  def parse(self, response):

    for company_url in response.xpath('//div[@class="search_result_title"]/a/@href').extract():
      yield scrapy.Request(
          url=response.urljoin(company_url),
          callback=self.parse_details,
      )

  def parse_details(self, response):

    # Looping throught the searchResult block and yielding it

    for i in response.css('div.col-md-6'):
      yield {
          'company_name': i.css('#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)::text').get(),
          'address': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
          'location': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3)::text").extract_first(),
          'postal_code': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(5) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
      }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The HTML on those pages is totally invalid - it has many duplicate IDs - so you may never be able to get proper results from it. In any case, you should consider using the actual [Companies House API](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/) rather than trying to scrape this dodgy site.

Comment: Thank you very much i will look into that API!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements `div.col-md-6` one each company page (example: https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/ltd/a-c-1). So, first has company details and second one contains map and no company data.

So, you can modify you code with:

```
def parse_details(self, response):
    for i in response.css('div.col-md-6'):
        if not i.css('#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1)'):
            continue
        yield {
            'company_name': i.css('#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > strong:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)::text').get(),
            'address': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
            'location': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3)::text").extract_first(),
            'postal_code': i.css("#content2 > strong:nth-child(2) > address:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(5) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract_first(),
        }
```

So, just skip items that initially do not have needed block.

Comment: Super dodgy I never noticed it. Also funny how it never crossed my mind that there could be two elements. I will look out in the future! Thank you very much vezunchik!